# Issue with bestglm in R - S and F counts can not be <0

Tags: r, machine-learning, subset, logistic-regression

I tried to do subset regression with `bestglm`, but when I executed it, I got the following error

```
Error in bestglm(Xy=H.bestglm2, family = binomial, IC ="AC", method = "exhaustive": 
Binomial non-logistic regression: S and F counts can not be <0
```

I have no idea what this means and I can't find any information regarding this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: My guess is S and F means success and failure, respectively. You probably have negative values in `Xy`.

Comment: The thing is, there are no negative values. In my dataset I have dates, earnings (positive values), binary and categorical variables (10 levels max).

Comment: Have you studied the documentation? You probably didn't specify the LHS correctly for a binomial GLM. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Yes, I did. And I used a code from this site: [link](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/2897_9220b21cfc0c43a396ff9abf122bb351.html). My final dataset looks like this: 

**center.cat** : Factor w/2 levels (0,1) 
**MONTH** : POSIXct, format: "2016-06-18" ....
**holiday.cat**: Factor w/2 levels (0,1)
**CODE**: int 22 23
**category.cat**: Factor w/10 levels (1:10)
**L1Earnings** : num (various numbers)
**L2Earnings** : num (various numbers)

**Six lag factors with two levels (0,1)**
**Six lag factors with three levels (0:2)**

**y**: num (1,0) - outcome variable.

Comment: I don't know what to do. I tried to reproduce the example from above website and it worked. But I have no idea why this code doesn't work for my dataset.

Comment: The documentation clearly states that `Xy` should be a "[d]ataframe containing the design matrix X and the output variable y". Did you create a design matrix (with your factors dummy encoded)? Please show the output of `str(Xy)` or preferably, if it is not too huge, of `dput(Xy)`.

Comment: I managed to deal with this issue thanks to your advice about dput(Xy),apparently there were some invisible empty rows imported from xls file. So thank you for this!

I have one more question. Is there a way to tell how long will the execution of bestglm take?

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure that the response variable (which must be in the last column) is binary, then try this:

```
H.bestglm2 <- data.frame(H.bestglm2)
```

and then run bestglm on the new object

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if the documentation for bestglm is incomplete. I was running into this error as well and could not find anything wrong with my data frame.  Eventually, while substituting my columns of data into an existing, working data.frame (SAheart from the bestglm examples) I figured out that the Xy data frame appears to just use the last column as the outcome variable.

This fails:

```
> set.seed(1)
> test.data=data.frame(y=rbinom(100,1,.5),X=rnorm(100))
> bestglm(test.data,family=binomial)
Error in bestglm(test.data, family = binomial) : 
  Binomial nonlogistic-regression: S and F counts can not be <0
```

But this works:

```
> set.seed(1)
> test.data=data.frame(X=rnorm(100),y=rbinom(100,1,.5))
> bestglm(test.data,family=binomial)
Morgan-Tatar search since family is non-gaussian.
BIC
Best Model:
              Estimate Std. Error   z value   Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -0.4895482  0.2060214 -2.376201 0.01749194
```

No matter how my variables are named, it always just seems to grab the last column to use as the outcome (y) variable. In the first case, that produces the error because that column is not strictly 0/1 so it doesn't think you're doing a logistic regression.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still getting this issue, passing a tibble to the function didn't work. When I converted it to a dataframe, it worked just fine.